# Smooth function and integrals

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a little issue with an exercice.

Let F be a $C^1$ map from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

We introduce three propositions :

(a) : $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} F(t) \textrm{dt}$ is converging

(b) : $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} tF'(t) \textrm{dt}$ is converging

(c) : $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} x F(x) = 0$

The first question is about finding all implications between this three propositions. I think that if two propositions hold then it implies that the last one hold too.

In the second question, we assume that F is a positive and discreasing function. What do our implcations become ? I tried to use the fact that F is positive then we can use Fubini-Tonelli theorem but I didn't find new implications (or weaker implcations ..)

Answer (score 1):

By parts,

$$\int_0^\infty F(t)\,dt=\left.tF(t)\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty tF'(t)\,dt.$$

This shows a relation between the three statements.